# How to go to a specific file in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a web application with a heavy front-end approach. By using Dojo and the AMD-way, I currently have testing screens which may easily load over a hundred different javascript files.

When I want to debug for any specific problem, or verify if I am seeing an old version of a specific file, I find it really hard to find my files in the Sources tab in the Chrome Developer Tools.

Is there any shortcut or action I can make that will let me type the name of a file and will take me to the source of that file?

Comment: On the bottom right of the console, there is a gear icon. Click it. On the last tab in the settings window there is a shortcuts tab. You can see the key combos like the answer.

Comment: Use 'Go to file' in Google Dev Tools (a flexible and useful tool with ability search on your function name, class name in CSS, ...)['Go to file' in Google Dev Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47690078/7487135)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

While in the sources tab use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for Mac) to search scripts, stylesheets and snippets by filename.

(use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to filter/navigate to a JavaScript function/CSS rule when viewing a file)

[[Chrome Devtools Cheatsheet](http://anti-code.com/devtools-cheatsheet/)]

Comment: This is good to know! You used to (before Chrome 35?) be able to start a filename search by just typing with the file navigator in the Sources tab focused; it's good to know that they've hidden this feature behind a shortcut rather than removing it completely. =)

Comment: the caveat to the filter/search is that you can't seem to do exact searches or wildcards. searching for `.js` returns any file with a `j` or an `s` or a `.` in the filename :/

Comment: When I go to open a file, I see multiple version of same files. I have to go through each file to find the appropriate file. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 31):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> brings up the search input on Windows.

[image]

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> — on Mac.

[image]

Comment: `O` and `P` seem to have the same behavior. I wonder if one is deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

In Windows:

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>  to search for content in files.

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>  to search for file names.

Comment: If using a build process, and the files are no longer recognizable in chrome, searching by content is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Mac: Command + O
Windows: Ctrl + O