# Chrome DevTools search all javascript files in website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a new client's website that loads Javascript from a CDN so the Javascript is not embedded or inline with the webpage source. **I would like to pause everytime `getCurrentPosition()` is executed** in order to determine which external JS file it is contained in.

I realize I could use other tools to do a string search through the contents of the JS files but I would rather keep to Chrome's debugging tools.

Should I be trying to create a watch expression or is there another way to pin down when and where a certain JS function is fired?

Comment: Do you know where `getCurrentPosition` is defined? Where it's called?

Comment: There is search in the Google tools. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145266/how-to-search-all-loaded-scripts-in-chrome-developer-tools/7970237#7970237

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search all loaded scripts in Chrome Developer Tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145266/how-to-search-all-loaded-scripts-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: Use 'Go to file' in Google Dev Tools (a flexible and useful tool with ability search on your function name, class name in CSS, ...). [More info:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47690078/7487135)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can search in all files using Chrome DevTools. Find your function and debug it:

1. Open DevTools (F12)
2. Go to sources tab
3. Open Search All Files by pressing `ctrl + shift + f` (Win) or `cmd + option + f` (Mac)
4. Search *getCurrentPosition*
5. Put a breakpoint (By clicking the line number at the left of the line)

[image]

Comment: This helped me find what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Nice, did not know that DevTools had a "Search all sources" option.

Comment: `Cmd+Option+F` on Mac

Comment: Bless your soul! This made the source code digging infinitely easier <3

Answer (score 23):

1. Open Google Dev tools(F12)
2. Press Ctrl + p

In the opened box search for all files(JS, CSS, ...).

[image: search all files in javascript]

In the box you have 5 options:

[image]
At the first select a file for using options 2-5

1. Type 'filename' and select it.
2. Type ':linenumber' to go to specific line number(':10' go to line 10).
3. Type '@symbol' to go to specific symbol('@TestSymbol' go to TestSymbol symbol).

In this option, if you write @JSFunctionName or @CSSClassName then the cursor
will navigate to the JSFunctionName or the CSSClassName.

4. Type '!snippet' to go to specific snippet('!snippetTest' go to snippetTest snippet).
5. Type '>googleCommand' to go to specific command('>Clear console' clear the console).

Comment: totally worth scrolling beyond the recommended answer; this is a lot of help

Answer (score 3):

You can find all the information that you need at the webpage: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

[image]

By simply putting it (copied from the webpage)

> Open a site such as the Google Closure hovercard demo page or the TodoMVC
>
> 1. Open a site such as the Google Closure hovercard demo page or the TodoMVC Angular app
> 2. Open the DevTools window.
> 3. If it is not already selected, select Sources.

**Debugging with breakpoints**

> A breakpoint is an intentional stopping or pausing place in a script. Use breakpoints in DevTools to debug JavaScript code, DOM updates, and network calls.
>
> Add and remove breakpoints
>   In the Sources panel, open a JavaScript file for debugging. In the example below, we are debugging the todoCtrl.js file from the AngularJS version of TodoMVC.
>
> Click the line gutter to set a breakpoint for that line of code. A blue tag will indicate if a breakpoint has been set:

[image]

With the above simple example you can actually "stop" the function `getCurrentPosition()` and debug it.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to replace the `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition` method with a wrapper function so that you can set a breakpoint inside it, and then examine the stack to see who is calling it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know where in the code the method is called you can [set breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en). This will pause the javascript execution during runtime and allow you get a stack trace.