# How to find a string that is used in javascript files in a web page

Tags: javascript, browser

There is a web page that loads multiple javascript files.

And I want to search for a string for in all files like a `grep`.

Of course I can grep them if I download all the files, but I'd rather search them using development tools in a web browser.

Is there a easy way to search all javascript files that are loaded by a web page for a string?

Comment: Is your question about searching js code in developer tools?  - in firefox you could in the debug tab (developer version 52 they've changed the debug tab to be less useful in this regard) - not sure about other browsers - which browser are you working with?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/37685351/5749914

Comment: in chrome, open dev tools, click sources tab, hit ctrl+shift+f, type string you want to search and hit enter, boom.